# comparison goes faulty c# Dictionary<String, string[]>

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, dictionary

Good day all,

I have a `Dictionary<String, String[])>`, with a key => value example like the following:

```
{ "Eten/drinken", new string[] { "canteen", "mcdonald's", "mimi" } }
```

I need to compare a string `part` with one of the values of the Dictionary:

```
 if (categories.Any(x => x.Value.Contains(part))) {
        category = categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Contains(part)).Key;
 }
```

In one scenario `part = "mcdonald's veghel veghel"`, which makes the comparison with the Dictionary value come back `false`.

Why is it false? `"mcdonald's veghel veghel"` does contain `mcdonald's` and zero-space comparisons do go the way they should.

Comment: Because none of them contains the `"mcdonald's veghel veghel"` substring.

Comment: *Why is it false?* -- well, you compared `"mcdonald's veghel veghel"` to `{ "canteen", "mcdonald's", "mimi" }`. If you want to compare whether the value contains any word from the `part` variable, you'll need to split your `"mcdonald's veghel veghel"` into `{"mcdonald's", "veghel"}` and then check whether all of them exists in the dictionary's array..

Comment: Funny thing, this is actually what I did before in my code but thought it would be too devious. Thank you for making things clear for me though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the `String.Contains` method will check for any specified subsring present in the given string. unfortunately there is  no `x.Value` that contains the given string, whereas the given values contains item/s of x.Value, so you have to change your query like the following:

```
var collectionResult = categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Any(s=> part.Contains(s)));
if(collectionResult != null)
{
   var selectedKey =  collectionResult.Key;
}
```

Comment: good idea, it can be done this way rather than splitting the part.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, and for the quickness of this reply!

Comment: @MwBakker: No mention, we are all here to help. Happy to help you buddy

Answer (score 3):

Expression inside lambda `x.Value.Contains(part)` means that any of the elements of `{"canteen", "mcdonald's", "mimi"}` contains the string `"mcdonald's veghel veghel"`, which is `false`. You wanted the inverse of the condition, i.e. where the long string `part` contains any of the keywords from your list:

```
categories.Any(x => x.Value.Any(s => part.Contains(s)))
```

Comment: @zerkms You are right, there needs to be another `Any`.

Comment: Thank you! Quick response and great suggestion

Comment: Still it checks for existence only, Actually op is taking the `.Key` corresponds to the item. I think you have to do some edits to make it perfect. thank you